# if condition with "and" combine "multiple or" in Vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have been making validation in macro vba...

How to make if condition with "and" combined with "multiple or" in vba?

Here is my code:

```
If (not cook = True) And (if (exp_gas > 0) or (exp_woodburn > 0) or _
    (exp_oil > 0) or (margarine > 0)) Then
    MsgBox "He doesn't cook", vbInformation 

End If
```

It gives me syntax error.

Comment: Change `And (if` to `And (`  (I'm not having much luck with this comment - that's about the 10th edit I have made!)

Comment: what is exp_gas ???

Comment: drop the second `if`, it is causing the syntax error. the logic of the If statement may be wrong though.  each part, of the If clause, has to reduce to true/false

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? If you don't want to cook, and if the gas or woorburn is greater than zero while the or margarine is greater than zero, display that message box? ...Wouldn't you just need to know `not cook = True` to know `He doesn't cook`, :P

Comment: it works.. thank you Sir,

Comment: i think that you want this.  ... start with `if cook and fuel and fat then` ... then reverse logic  `if not (cook and fuel and fat) then` ... then expand fuel and fat (brackets around each)... `If Not (cook And ((exp_gas > 0) Or (exp_woodburn > 0)) And ((exp_oil > 0) Or (margarine > 0))) Then`

Comment: Yes, Sir. i've been making a editing coding program with VBA for household questionnaire of expenditure. but, i still a new learning about macro hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `If` statement in condition in another `If` statement. One solution is to use nested `If`'s, for more info look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_nested_if_statements.htm). Another solution is to get rid of `If` inside condition, so your code would look like this (i think this is exactly what you need):

```
If (not cook = True) And ((exp_gas > 0) or (exp_woodburn > 0) or _
    (exp_oil > 0) or (margarine > 0)) Then
    MsgBox "He doesn't cook", vbInformation 

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

the compiler cannot understand these conditions.
we need to split the conditions and display the required.
please use multiple if statements for this

```
If (not cook = True) And (if (exp_gas > 0)  Then
     
MsgBox "He doesn't cook", vb Information 

End If

If((exp_woodburn > 0) or _(exp_oil > 0)) then
    
MsgBox "He doesn't cook", vbInformation 

End if
```