# Not Like has no effect while looping an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am using the below code to loop the array, But the last condition `And Not...like` has no effect at all.
thanks for your help.

```
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 2) Like "*Helideck*" Or _
       arr(i, 5) Like "*-HD-*" And _
       Not arr(i, 16) Like "*Fire*" Then arrH(i, 1) = "True"
```

Comment: Since you are combining and/or you may benefit from adding some parentheses that control the order. Another option that may be more clear would be to nest your if statements (break them apart for finer control)

Comment: @braX ,I tried nested if and it works, But I will keep the question, may be there is another option.

Comment: Well as i said, you can add parentheses instead... mixing an `Or` with the `And` can be tricky, but using the parentheses properly can accomplish what you want as well. Here's a rough example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704996/if-condition-with-and-combine-multiple-or-in-vba-excel

Comment: @braX , I found that it even dose not need the parentheses , I just changed the order and also works, anyhow I have post an answer with your ideas 

Comment: Changing the order works because you have problem with or / and, like brax explained already. I'm quite sure now your fire rule works with helideck, but not with hd rule. Just add parenthesis, that's the whole problem you have.

Comment: @James Z , my fire rule works also with "`HD`" even without parenthesis at all, kindly see my answer (second option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this idea of @braX and it works.

```
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 2) Like "*Helideck*" Then arrH(i, 1) = "True"
    If arr(i, 5) Like "*-HD-*" Then arrH(i, 1) = "True"
    If arr(i, 16) Like "*Fire*" Then arrH(i, 1) = ""
Next i
```

and there is another working method:

```
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If Not arr(i, 16) Like "*Fire*" And _
      arr(i, 2) Like "*Helideck*" Or _
      arr(i, 5) Like "*-HD-*" Then arrH(i, 1) = "True"
Next i
```